# How to customize the datetime format of json before web api send out the response?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

the default DateTime format my webapi returned is not what I want.
How to customize it?

Comment: The default date time format return is presumably ISO 8601. A universally portable date format which is great for transport too. If you want to format the date into some other format you should receive the 8601 date and then format it accordingly. Virtually any formatting library can handle 8601, if it can't, stop using it!

Answer (score 0):

Create DateTime Converter Class

```
public class DateTimeConverter : DateTimeConverterBase 

{
    public string DateTimeFormat { get; set; } 

    public DateTimeConverter() 
    { 
        this.DateTimeFormat = "MMM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"; //PUT HERE ANY FORMAT YOU NEED! 
    } 


    public override object ReadJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, 
    Type objectType, object existingValue, 
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer) 
    { 
        if (objectType == typeof(DateTime)) 
        { 
            //SEE HERE WHY. 
            throw new NotSupportedException("DateTime not allowed"); 
        } 
        else if (objectType == typeof(DateTimeOffset)) 
        { 
            reader.Read();
            reader.Read();
            DateTime dt = (DateTime)reader.Value; 

            reader.Read();
            reader.Read();
            Int64 offsetinMin = (Int64)reader.Value; 

            DateTime utcTime = new DateTime(dt.AddMinutes(-offsetinMin).Ticks, 
            DateTimeKind.Utc); 

            reader.Read();

            return new DateTimeOffset(utcTime, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0)); 
        } 
        else 
            return null; 
    } 



    public override void WriteJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer, 
           object value, 
           Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer) 
    { 
        if (value is DateTime) 
        { 
            DateTime utcTime = (DateTime)value; 
            writer.WriteRawValue(String.Format("\"{0}\"", 
           ((DateTime)utcTime.ToLocalTime()).ToString(this.DateTimeFormat)));                
        } 

        else if (value is DateTimeOffset) 
        { 
            DateTimeOffset offs = (DateTimeOffset)value; 
            writer.WriteRawValue(String.Format("\"{0} UTC({1:##})\"", 
            offs.ToString(this.DateTimeFormat), offs.Offset.Minutes)); 
        } 
    } 

}
```

Add this function to a Controller

```
protected ActionResult WriteJson(object data, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
{
    HttpResponseBase response = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response;

    response.ContentType = "application/json";

    using (JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(response.Output) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented })
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings sett = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        // THE CUSTOM FORMATTER 
        sett.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());
        JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(sett);

        serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
        writer.Flush();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
 WriteJson(new { data = XYZObjects }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```